# Empty return in ajax call if I call a method inside

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I would like to ask a question about a problem in ajax:

```
  $.ajax({
    url: "wikiLoader.php?keyword=" + nomeRicerca+"&username="+nomeUtente,
    type: 'GET',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(res) {
        console.log(res);
        content.annotator("loadAnnotations", res);
    },
    error: function(xhr, textStatus, error) {
        ...
    }
});
```

In my console res is empty when I print it, but inside the function content.annotator("loadAnnotations", res) it works well and res infact is not empty. If I comment the function content.annotator("loadAnnotations", res) I see the real content of res that is a json object
Thank you in advance for the answer

Comment: Where is the code for `content.annotator()` ?

Comment: This is Annotatorjs library so that is an existent method. But I have not problems with the method, mine was just a curiosity because I can't print the res value if I execute the method

Comment: If res is an object, you'll need to decide which properties you are interested in printing and output them to the console like `console.log(res.propertyName);`

Comment: I have not problem in printing res if I comment the content.annotator("loadAnnotations", res); command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The AJAX call is still being executed as your code moves on to the console.log(res) line, so the message variable has no value.

You need to pass the value of the response to a function within the success method.

```
success: function(res) {
  printValue(res);
}
```

// outside AJAX call

```
function printValue(res) {
    console.log(res);
    var content = res;
    content.annotator("loadAnnotations", content);
}
```

Comment: I tried it, but if I write :
success: function(res) {
            printValue(res);
            content.annotator("loadAnnotations", res);
        }
When I call printValue() it gives me an empty object, without content.annotator instead it works well

Comment: try adding content.annotator in the printValue function outside the AJAX call

Comment: I don't see loadAnnotations anywhere in the AnnotatorJs docs. Maybe there's a problem with your usage of the function.

Comment: No, I correctly load annotations on my webpage, simply I wanted to modify res before loading but if i can't I can use it in this way without problem. Simply I would like to understand it

Comment: Well if you want to modify res before putting it in your page simply assign a variable to it and then pass this variable to content.annotator. I will modify my answer as following. It's probable content.annotator that is modifying res and then the browser console updates itself causing it not to show.

Comment: I just tried it, it would like as if annotator's function uses res but using it makes it empty

Comment: Yes it's possible. Assigning to a new variable should correct the problem.

Comment: success: function(res) {
            var temp = res;
            temp.quote = "So sick";
            console.log(temp);
            content.annotator("loadAnnotations", res);
        }
I made it but not is printed temp as only with the new attribute

Comment: Yes however you're passing the unmodified variable to content.annotator().